# Use TuxGuitars as VST

Tags: software, synthesizer, tuxguitar

This is certainly an odd request, but I grew up learning guitar with tuxguitar. I am used to "synthetic" guitars sounding like crap, in particular, like TuxGuitars synths. Can I get them out of tuxguitar, to use them as vsts? The interface is horrid, and writing in tuxguitar is a hassle. I'd rather use the synth in Ableton.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Tux uses external soundbanks (you can change btw) so they have to be somewhere. Any basic SB online would give you the same kind of sound, but is it possible to input that in Ableton...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/files/TuxGuitar/TuxGuitar-1.5.6/ and download one of the archive format files and look for the soundfont files (.sf2).

E.g. if you download the src-Package this contains a directory TuxGuitar-resources/resources/soundfont/MagicSFver2.sf2 or if your download one of the build packages you’ll get share/soundfont/MagicSFver2.sf2.

Then fetch yourself any kind of VST-capable soundfont based synth.

Theoretically it would be possible to separate the internal synthesizer of TuxGuitar from the rest of the code and make it VST-capable, but there is no point to it.